# Authbot login service returns link saying "ClientID not supported for this API"

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, botframework

I am running the [samplev2 AuthBot example](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot/tree/master/SampleAADv2Bot) and can access the login page successfully. However when it redirects to the login page for my bot it shows a page that says "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." The top link contains the error:

AADSTS70001 - Application is not supported for this API version

Where can I go to enable this type of API? I have already visited https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList to see whether my bot is there...and it is, but its in a section delegated as "Azure AD only Applications". When I click on it it simply shows the Application Manifest and I am unsure what I need to change to be able to allow users to login using AuthBot's authentication method.

Does anyone know how to get around this? Thanks.

EDIT: Something that may be relevant is that my bot's sign in link does work when I plug it into my browser. Just not working with AuthBot for some reason.

Comment: Have you done this (https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBot/blob/gh-pages/docs/CreateAzureADforAzureBot.md) for your bot? (the instructions are for AzureBot but are similar for any other bot)

Comment: @EzequielJadib Yes I have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the confusion here is between V1 and V2 applications.
Recently, Microsoft introduced a new V2 application model which is described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview).

It seems like you are trying to use a V1 application to access a V2 endpoint, which will simply not work today. The error message you are getting is saying that the V2 endpoint is expecting an access token from a V2 application. Even though you can see your application in the `apps.dev.microsoft.com`, you noted that it is in the "Azure AD Only" section, which means it is a V1 application.

Start at the `apps.dev.microsoft.com` portal, and register a new V2 application (also known as converged application), and you should gain access to the API endpoint you are trying to reach.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this was it! I just switched to using the V1 protocol for AuthBot and it worked! :)